# Issues deploying to gh-pages after building a static site with Gulp

Tags: html, gulp, github-pages

I am building a static website using Gulp, BrowserSync, and all is working well up until the point where I push my changes up to my gh-pages branch, hoping that it will render correctly via the gh-pages website that I'm creating.  I have done some research, and I know that because of the way that gh-pages works, the path that I use for links, images, etc will have to include the root directory... and some of the changes I have made to the code will work, but it ultimately screws up how the page works while running it locally with gulp.  On top of that, I'm having an issue with loading a partial html page via jquery, which I believe also has to do with the path being wrong when hosted on gh-pages.  Everything works fine when I run it locally with gulp.  If I just open up the index.html page from terminal, it works fine, but once I click a link, things get messy.  Does anyone know of a thorough tutorial, video, blog, or happen to know a good way to set up my directory to ensure that it will work both locally as well as when it's pushed up to gh-page?  I've included a photo that shows how my directory is currently set up. [image]

My gulpfile looks like this

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

    gulp.task('styles', function () {
       return gulp.src('./scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
    });

    gulp.task('serve', function () {
      browserSync.init({
        server: {
          baseDir: './'
        }
      });

      gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
      gulp.watch('./**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
   });

   gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'serve']);
```

Here is the website as it is currently on gh-pages:  https://andrewdpohl.github.io/STHR/

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you know the base path on your local dev, and you know the base path on GH pages, can't you make a seperate build setting that replaces the base path in your code?

Comment: Not exactly sure how I would do that.  Do you mean run a gulp task that essentially takes ALL of my files and put them in their own folder, which would be published to gh-pages?

Answer (score 0):

The use of `.src()` is documented on the vinyl-fs github repo:
https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs

The `base` property is used to determine the file names when saving in `.dest()`.

**I think you need to set the current working directory**:

```
gulp.src('./**/*.js', {cwd: '../src/main/'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../target/dist'));
```